# Javascript Onclick Button - Un-do an action on second click

Tags: javascript, css

sorry in advance if it's a noobish question I'm asking because I'm a newbie at Javascript.

Basically I've got a sidebar containing information hidden by overflow:hidden. I wanted to create a simple function: a button that onClick would change the values of the sidebar DIV to width:100%, height:100%, position:absolute. I did it no problems. However I hoped there was a way of making the button un-do and revert to original values on the second click, **whatever the original values are**, and I can't discover how to do it. Sound simple but I wonder if there's a way?

Thanks in advance and sorry again if it's a silly question.

Comment: you can just toggle a class with these styles

Answer (score 4):

Create those styles in css (for example class .extended) and by javascript add/remove this class when needed.

Comment: Clearly, the OP is asking how to do this. Your answer doesn't really help. You should provide code.

Comment: Absolutely crazy that this answer is getting up voted. It is essentially the same as "Just write the code to do it.".

Comment: My bad, sorry.
Next time as you provided code to solve the issue.

PS. I thought he knows how o add class as he was able to add styles from javascript.

Comment: As astounding as it may sound I did not think of it because the sidebar I'm editing is a class, but it makes enough sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can set a default style and then **[toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)** another one on and off.

Since they are both classes, their specificity will be the same. In this case, the last class applied will go into effect and override the one applied earlier.

```js
// Get a reference to the button
var btn = document.getElementById("btnToggle");
var sidebar = document.getElementById("sidebar");

// When the button is clicked, run an event handling function
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
   // Toggle the application of the "expanded" class. If it is not 
   // currently being applied, apply it (overriding the previously 
   // applied class of the same specificity). And, if it is currently
   // applied, then remove it (thus, restoring the rules from the default
   // class, which was never actually taken away).
   sidebar.classList.toggle("expanded");
});
```

```css
/* 
  These properties/value apply to the side bar all the time.
  Notice that this selector is ID based, which gives it a 
  specificity of 100 (very specific and hard to override).
*/
#sidebar {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.3); 
  height:100vh;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  padding:15px;
}

/* 
  This class is initially applied in the HTML and only
  contains the properties/values that need to be overidden
  later. It has a specificity value of 10
*/
.normal { width:5%; overflow:hidden; }

/* 
  This class will be added/removed via JavaScript. 
  It also has a specificity value of 10 (ties with the
  .normal class), so when it is added, any property
   settings that conflict with earlier settings will 
   override those earlier settings. And, when this class
   is removed, the earlier settings will no longer be 
   overridden, so they will come back into effect.
*/
.expanded { width:25%; overflow:auto; }
```

```html
<button id="btnToggle">Toggle Sidebar</button>
<div id="sidebar" class="normal">
  <h1>Side Bar</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>some content</li>
    <li>some content</li>
    <li>some content</li>    
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Got it now. Yes, it's why I couldn't do it. Thanks a lot, I'll be testing and replying.